# Better option to fetch results from database tables

Tags: java, database, jdbc, plsql, oracle10g

Are there any performance improvement in calling a procedure which returns `SYS_RECURSOR` or call a query?

For example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc
(
  p_id number,
  emp_cursor IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN

OPEN emp_cursor for
select * from emp where emp_number=p_id
end;
/
```

and call the above from `Java` by registering `OUT` parameter,pass `IN` parameter and fetch the results.

Or

From `Java` get the results from `emp` `table` by

```
preparedStatement = prepareStatement(connection, "select * from emp where emp_number=?", values); 
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Which one of the above is a better option to call from `Java`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance difference assuming your `prepareStatement` method is using the appropriate type for all bind variables.  That is, you would need to ensure that you are calling `setLong`, `setDate`, `setString`, etc. depending on the data type of the parameter.  If you bind the data incorrectly (i.e. calling `setString` to bind a numeric value), you may force Oracle to do data type conversion which may prevent the optimizer from using an index that would improve performance.

From a code organization and maintenance standpoint, however, I would rather have the queries in the database rather than in the Java application.  If you find that a query is using a poor plan, for example, it's likely to be much easier for a DBA to address the problem if the query is in a stored procedure than if the query is embedded in a Java application.  If the query is stored in the database, you can also use the database's dependency tracking functions to more easily do an impact analysis if you need to do something like determine what would be impacted if the `emp` table needs to change.

Comment: From maintenance and other point of view I guess it is a good idea to keep the query in stored procedures. What exactly you meant by `prepareStatement method is using the appropriate type for all bind variables`. Could be kind enough to explain a bit more? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think there is major significant difference from the *Java invocation* standpoint.

Some differencesI can think of are:

- You will now have to maintain two different code bases: your Java code and your stored procedures. In case of errors, you will have to debug in two different places, and fix problems in two different places.
- Once production-ready, making changes to the database is probably going to require some additional formalisms besides those required to change the Java code deployed.
- Another important matter to take into account is database-independence, if you are building a product to work with different kinds of databases, you would be forced to write different versions of your stored procedures and you will have more code to maintain (debug, bugfix, change, etc).
- This very important if you're building a product that you intend to deploy in different environments of different (possible yet unknown) clients, wich you cannot predict what RDBMS will be using.
- If you want to use an ORM framework i.e. Hibernate, EclipseLink) it will generate pretty optimized queries for you. Plus, it would be more difficult to integrate it later on if you use stored-procedures.
- With proper amount of logging is easy to analyze your queries for optimization purposes. You could use JDBC logging or the logging provided by your ORM provider and actually see how the query is being used by the application, how many times, how often, etc, and optimize where it matters.

Comment: Yes once in production I may have to change two places if there is a change in table structure. It is a good practice to fetch rows by `resultSet.getstring("emp_name")` or `resultSet.getstring(2);`? By specifying `2` as position we do not need to worry about column names in `java` isn't it?

Comment: @Polappan Using an integer instead of a name will simplify changes if you rename columns, but it will make the code harder to understand in the mapping between result sets and objects. Also, what if you re-arrange the order of columns or if you remove a column? I would say the benefit is not so big. Also I updated my answer to include other decision criteria.

Comment: I have another question, is it better to use a `function` or a `procedure` to fetch records from a table? In other words use `sys_refcursor` which returns records from a `function` or `sys_refcursor` returns records from a `procedure`?